# jQuery: Close Dialog after AJAX submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, jquery-ui

After submitting by AJAX, I'd like to have the form close. I looked up on Google and some old topics here, but I couldnt find anything! I have one function i javascript to show my forms and I have another one to ajax request, i think i should get the instance of open modal window and then close it, but im not sure.

Here is the code to show the form window

```
$(function (){
function handler() {
if (this.readyState == this.DONE) {
    if (this.status == 200 && this.responseText != null) {
        $("#modal").html(this.responseText);
        return;
    }
    console.log('Something went wrong! Status = ' + this.status);
 }
}

var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.onreadystatechange = handler;

$(document).ready(function () {
   $(document).on('click','.showModal',function(event) {
    client.open("GET", $(this).attr("href"),true);
    client.send();
var dialog;
dialog =   $("#modal").dialog({
        autoOpen:true,
        width: 400,
        height: 450,
        modal: true,
        /*close: function () {
            $("#modal").html('');
        }*/
        buttons: [{ 
           text: "Cancelar", 
           click: function() { 
             dialog.dialog("close"); 
           }
        }],
        close: function () {
            $("#modal").html('');
        }

    });
    return false;
 });

});
});
```

Here is the code through which I'm sending data by AJAX, and trying to close the window with afterward:

```
$(function(){
$("#y").on('click',function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var id = $("input[name=id]").val();
     var action = 'del';
     $.post("album/ajax",{
          action : action,
          id     : id
        },
        function(data){
          if(data.response == true){
            if(action == 'del') {
              var table = $('#table');
              table.find('tr').each(function(indice){
              $(this).find('td').each(function(indice){
                if($(this).text() == ''){
                var valor = $(this).find('input[name=cod]').val();
                 if(valor == id){
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                    /*var dialog;
                    dialog =   $("#modal").dialog();
                    dialog.closest(".ui-dialog-content").dialog("close");
                    dialog.dialog("close");*/
                  }
                }
             });
            });
           }
         } else {
               alert("Nao foi possivel deletar!");

         }
        },'json');

 });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to close a jQuery dialog after an AJAX JSON call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16085422/how-to-close-a-jquery-dialog-after-an-ajax-json-call)

Comment: I already had taken a look over there, but no one worked for me. I still have the same trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Try $("#modal").dialog("close");

Comment: i did it and i got this error message Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'

Comment: I don't quite follow your code. Does this all happen on one page? 
And so you called $("#modal").dialog("close"); immediately after $(this).closest('tr').remove(); ?

Comment: I was testing, but yes it happens with all my modals dialog, i just declare my var dialog as global, it solved but im not sure if is the best way!